# Iteratively replace text in string using a key

Tags: r, stringi

I'm looking to iteratively replace the text in a string using a key. I have the code below but I'm wondering if there is an easier or more efficient way to do it

```
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

old_texts = c("blah blah value1 blah blah value2",
             "blah value1 blah value2")

key = data_frame(
  old = c("value1", "value2"),
  new = c("value3", "value4") ) 

replace_key_individual = function(old_text, key)
  key %>%
  mutate(call = paste0(
    "stri_replace_all_fixed('", old, "','", new, "')") ) %>%
  summarize(new_call = 
              call %>%
              paste(collapse = " %>% ")) %>%
  `$`(new_call) %>%
  paste("old_text %>% ", .) %>%
  parse(text = .) %>%
  eval

replace_key = function(old_texts, key)
  old_texts %>%
  sapply(. %>% replace_key_individual(key)) %>%
  unname

replace_key(old_texts, key = key)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you may simply want to try this:

```
old_texts %>% stri_replace_all_fixed(key$old, key$new, vectorize_all=FALSE)
#[1] "blah blah value3 blah blah value4"
#[2] "blah value3 blah value4"

# without the pipe operator:
stri_replace_all_fixed(old_texts, key$old, key$new, vectorize_all=FALSE)
```

Answer (score -1):

The base function gsub() uses regular expressions for text replacement. For example:

```
old_texts = c("blah blah value1 blah blah value2",
              "blah value1 blah value2")
new_text = gsub("value1", "value3", old_texts)
```

This function only replaces one value at a time, so you would still need to wrap it in something to implement your "old" and "new" key structure, but using it will greatly simplify your code.